# MVC| .Net| Excel export not responding when opened in MS Excel

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

Genterate an excel file from a view, is working fine if file has less data content but when the size gets bigger the file is not responding in MS-Exce. when i tried to open it, a message gets poped up showing:

[file is croupted or unsafe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGrBL.png)

and if I click yes to open, it fails to respond after taking to much time to load.

The code used to generate excel:

```
Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".xls\"");
                Response.Write("<html xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'>");
                return View(data);
```

Further, I also tried different options of ContentType and Extension but not get the result:

```
ContentType                         Extension       Result
application/ms-excel                .xls             No(Same issue)
application/vnd.ms-excel            .xls             No(Same issue)
application/ms-excel                .xlsx            No(Same issue)
application/vnd.ms-excel            .xlsx            No(Same issue)
application/vnd.openxmlformats-
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet  .xlsx            file opened a blank sheet
```

Comment: did you clear the response buffer and try?

Comment: I am actually working with Rajesh on this.  Some additional data - the file exports successfully afer downloaded when it's about 3.0 MB or less. Larger than that (in this case the file is 6 MB), it fails to open in Excel 2016. However it opens fine with OpenOffice.

Comment: Yes i cleared the response buffer and you can see in my shared code. Do i need to do something else?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Could someone please provide some inputs on this?